# pivot table in js with rtl lang

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I'm trying to use some pivot table in Javascript for data in Hebrew.
and I found two that look right for my needs -  Flexmonster and PivotTable.js

they worked fine, except when I tried to use the chart option, it shows me the text in the tags in reverse order.

this is the text label. I tried to add the css attribute:

```css
text {
  direction: rtl!important;
  unicode-bidi: embed!important;
}
```

```html
<text class="fm-label" dy="0.38em" transform="translate(354, 35.464988708496094) rotate(-60)" style="text-anchor: middle; cursor: auto;">חנויות דרום</text>
```

[image: this is how its look like]

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP3gz.png

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need `unicode-bidi: bidi-override` instead of `embed`.

```css
text {
  direction: rtl!important;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override!important;
}
```